# Grouping in iReport tool

Tags: java, jasper-reports, grouping, ireport

I am using **iReport 5.1.0** tool for report designing.
My Current report output is like,

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| STUDENT_ID | SUBJECT_NAME | SUBJECT_MARK | STUDENT_NAME |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |   Maths      |      25      |     John     |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |   English    |      35      |     John     |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     2      |   Maths      |      30      |     James    |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     2      |   English    |      23      |     James    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I need something like,

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| STUDENT_ID | SUBJECT_NAME | SUBJECT_MARK | STUDENT_NAME |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |   Maths      |      25      |     John     |
             -------------------------------
|            |   English    |      35      |              |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     2      |   Maths      |      30      |     James    |
             -------------------------------
|            |   English    |      23      |              |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is my **.jrxml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testStudent" language="groovy" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="752" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="31359f99-5457-4827-9bdb-e1160fe03bdc">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<field name="studentId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="studentName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="subjectName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="subjectMark" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="c04d7e4f-68ce-4519-a96d-8c4ba4dd4bba" x="0" y="0" width="205" height="31"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="20" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Test Students]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="3" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="04cf5bc0-ff69-47e3-af7c-b2702b1d5e90" x="0" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[STUDENT_ID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="b3c3a500-fb03-459f-b600-8ef738b3a795" x="300" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[STUDENT_NAME]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="04c057c8-e4cb-4ad9-876f-40ec3af568c4" x="100" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[SUBJECT_NAME]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="3f78e926-ed9e-4306-b0d7-cc03243bef4b" x="200" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[SUBJECT_MARK]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="e15a2c2c-76f7-40bb-bb88-dde1f89ff2d5" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{studentId}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="6da8fc6d-918b-4984-b374-57ab8669de80" x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{studentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="827a067f-e2a2-4a2e-a8f0-bf765e6ed241" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subjectName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="23463a34-0af0-4897-8745-6fe477919a83" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subjectMark}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="4" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="5" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="4" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary></jasperReport>
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml* file?

Comment: Did you use the *Data Grouping*?

Comment: Thanks Alex..no, I didn't use Data Grouping. Actually I don't know what is that.

Comment: Can you post your current *jrxml* file?

Comment: hi Alex..see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

[image]
First of all you should create a data group.

```
1.go to report inspector
2.right click on the jrxml name at the top of the report inpector 
3.select add report group. 
4.input the group name 
5. select the object, in your case student_id from the 'group by the following report   object'
6. click next 
7. Chose add report group header or footer or both if you want to. (in your case i think you should not add report group header or footer)
```

Your report group will be added.
Try to regenerate the report.
You should also uncheck 'print repeated values'

Comment: hi @Shann thanks but I tried same you said..but it's not working..after doing this in jrxml file is changing..but output is same.

Comment: it just giving me header and footer functionality if we needed..but I want to remove data duplication.

Comment: you should uncheck the header footer when asked for. can you also show your sql? for data replication uncheck 'print repeated values' from poroperties. select the text field and uncheck the print repeated values in properties
see screen shot to avoid repeated values above.

Comment: yes..when but when I uncheck 'print repeated values'..border is also removed for second row of groping in STUDENT_ID..but I want border around whole group as I print in question.

Comment: i did not get you. can you show the output.
and if possible your desired output also.

Comment: HI..Shann thanks..I already given my current as well desired output in my question..Just consider my dotted line with 1px continue border..and every-box width can be any.